# Numbers & css classes

Tags: php, css, numbers

How can I add a css class to a randomly generated number.

example:

```
if the number is under 2000 add a css class named red to the div <div class="red">500</div>
if the number is over  2000 add a css class named blue to the div <div class="blue">2500</div>
```

Comment: @Marcus He wants `<div>1</div>` to be transformed into `<div class="red">1</div>`, and `<div>2013</div>` to be transformed into `<div class="blue">2013</div>`

Comment: @Sime That makes sense, but what are the number 500 and 2500 doing in that sentence?

Comment: can you provide a less abstract code snippet?

Comment: @marcus.. those are the example rand numbers which were generated, i guess.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways this could be done, but here's one simple one. If `$rNum` holds your randomly-generated number we can test whether it is less than or equal to 2000. If it is, we'll print "red", and if it's not we'll print "blue".

```
<p class="<?php print ( $rNum <= 2000 ) ? "red" : "blue" ; ?>">Hello World</p>
```

If you're new to PHP you may find the syntax of the ternary operator to be somewhat confusion. It's basically a simplified inline if-else statement. You can see more examples and read a short description online at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 1):

you can first generate the rand number, store it into a variable and then use `if..else` to add the class to div element, like below:

```
<?php $rand = rand($min,$max); ?>
<div class="<?php if ( $rand <= 2000 ) echo "red"; else echo "blue" ; ?>"><?php echo $rand; ?></div>
```

Alternatively, add an `id` element to this div tag, and then use Javascript to add the class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do this?

```
<div class="<?php echo ($number<2000)?'red':'blue'; ?>">
 <?php echo $number ?>
</div>
```